# Segmentation fault in libev after fork

Tags: c, linux, fork, libev

I want to make an example application with `libev`. I want to have a watcher on keyboard input that will parse several commands like "start" "stop" "exit". On "start" I want to create a pipe and fork the application to start some worker(like `ffmpeg` with `exec()` or just some loop that prints some characters) in a child and set a watcher on this pipe in a parent to print output to console. On "stop" command I want to kill a child and remove a watcher.

I have implemented this program but after the fork I always get segfault on keyboard input when the child is running.

At first I thought that because if `STDIN` can be shared between child and parent. I've tried to detach child, close `STDIN` in child. Then I tried `dup` `STDIN` and close the default `STDIN` in parent at the beginning and set a watcher on duplicated `STDIN`. I also tried to close `STDOUT/ERR` descriptors before forking and restore them in the parent after the fork.

I stopped and start `user_input` watcher in `user_input` callback in case this could help.

Then I tried to execute `ev_default_fork()` and `ev_loop_fork()` in a child (this is not necessary because I want to `exec()` just after the fork or in any case the child loop never get a control) with no success.

I also tried to use different back-ends (`select` instead of `epoll`).

Also I tried to ignore some signals like `SIGHUP` `SIGPIPE` `SIGCHILD`.

I noticed also that my input after the `fork()` causes segfault and bash get it as a command so if I do something like this (With ">" I denote self-hand written input and with "<" the program and system output):

```
> $ ./libev_example
> start
< Debug: fork data got: 
< [Data got from child through pipe] 
> asd
< Segmentation fault (core dumped)
< $ asd
< bash: asd: command not found...
```

Then I built `libev` from sources and tried to debug. The segfault happens in `ev.c:1698`

```
  if (expect_false (w_->pending))
      pendings [pri][w_->pending - 1].events |= revents;
  else
```

the `pri` value is 4 and as I could understand it's a priority. `pendings[4]` is `0x0` so the segfault happens. When program doesn't crash code goes in `else` branch.

The fd that `epoll` returns is 0, but I didn't use 0 as fd in any event. Moreover for 0 there is a watcher in `loop->anfds` that has a callback to my `user_input` callback. In previous iteration, when I enter any string there was no event for 0. I checked the pipe fds and they are also have a number grater then 0.

I can't figure whats happen here and what I'm doing wrong. I can place here some code, but there is nothing special there. This post is quite big enough so if someone asks for the code I'll post it later.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Some time with gdb solved the problem. I found couple of errors in my code that has no straight connection with libev or fork.

And the problem that caused such strange behavior was my mistype that I didn't noticed due my inattention. I subclass the standard `ev_io` struct but for some reason I made this:

```
typedef struct lee_user_input_event_t{
    struct ev_io *event;
    struct lee_process_data_t *child_process_data;
...
};
```

Instead of this:

```
typedef struct lee_user_input_event_t{
    struct ev_io event;
    struct lee_process_data_t *child_process_data;
...
}
```

So casting the event pointer in callback to my own struct was a complete and huge disaster.